# Under what conditions is $u^x + v^y$ factorable for odd $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factoring

In what follows, suppose that $u, v \in \mathbb{N}$.  Furthermore, assume that $u \neq v$.

Under what conditions is
$$u^x + v^y$$
factorable for odd $x$ and $y$?

(I do know that it is factorable when $x=y$.  I would of course be interested in other conditions.)

Comment: yes, I missed that. (withdrew my comment accordingly).

Comment: @lulu, to address your other concern, I am using the term *factorable* here in the usual sense that we use the terminology in College Algebra, where things such as fields or rings have not been discussed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if $d:=\gcd(x,y)\ne 1$. Then $x=dx'$ and $y=dy'$ and we have:

$$ (u^{x'})^d+(v^{y'})^d = m^d+n^d = (m+n)(m^{d-1}-m^{d-2}n+...+n^{d-1})$$

wher $m= u^{x'}$ and $n=v^{y'}$

Comment: Thanks @johnnobody.  Would you care to sketch a quick proof please?

Comment: Thanks for the proof.  Did not see that coming.  Would you know of other conditions for which the expression is factorable?